# Trying to understand array with object and using it

Tags: php, arrays, function, object

Trying get a web based SONOS php-controller (see [git source](https://github.com/DjMomo/sonos)) to work and at the same time learn PHP. As expected I'm having trouble from the start.

The function `detect()` creates an array with objects.

```
$var = SonosPHPController::detect();
var_dump ($var);

array(3) {
    [0]=> object(SonosPHPController)#3 (4) { ["Sonos_IP":protected]=> NULL ["_raw":protected]=> array(0) { } ["IP"]=> string(13) "192.168.1.137" ["PORT"]=> int(1400) }
    [1]=> object(SonosPHPController)#7 (4) { ["Sonos_IP":protected]=> NULL ["_raw":protected]=> array(0) { } ["IP"]=> string(13) "192.168.1.134" ["PORT"]=> int(1400) }
    [2]=> object(SonosPHPController)#6 (4) { ["Sonos_IP":protected]=> NULL ["_raw":protected]=> array(0) { } ["IP"]=> string(13) "192.168.1.232" ["PORT"]=> int(1400) }
}
```

How do I make this into something useful like assigning each IP to a constant so I could use them in other functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "something useful"? You have it as a SonosPHPController object, so it's already something quite useful (otherwise you probably wouldn't have used it - would you?)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
$ipArray = array();

foreach($var as $item) {
    $ipArray[] = $item->IP;
}

var_dump($ipArray);
```

Would output

```
array(3) {
  [0] => string(13) "192.168.1.137"
  [1] => string(13) "192.168.1.134"
  [2] => string(13) "192.168.1.232"
}
```

Or you could go like this

```
$firstSonosController  = $var[0];
$secondSonosController = $var[1];
$thirdSonosController  = $var[2];
```

And then you can play around with it

```
echo $firstSonosController->IP;    // outputs 192.168.1.137
echo $secondSonosController->PORT; // outputs 1400
...
```